# Swift closure EXC_BAD_ACCESS only when embedded in a framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, closures

I have created a framework library that I am importing into another project. The library has a function that makes a network request, via another networking library called [AutoGraph](https://github.com/remind101/AutoGraph), and then performs some response manipulation before returning it to the caller. The issue is that after the network request is completed and it is about to return the data to my framework, the closure function it executes to return said data ends in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. However, if I include the source classes of the framework directly in the project, this error doesn't occur. So this would lead me to believe this isn't an issue in AutoGraph, but rather something to do with the way the framework is being packaged?

Here is the request that is made by the framework:

```
MyClient.shared.graphClient.send(GetNavigationHierarchy(paginationFilter: pageFilter, nodePaginationFilter: nodePageFilter, navigationRootFilter: navRootFilter)) { (response) in
        //Data manipulation
    }
```

**graphClient** is an instance of the AutoGraph networking library, which is a GraphQL library built on top of Alamofire.

Here is a link to the exact line where AutoGraph throws the EXC_BAD_ACCESS:
https://github.com/remind101/AutoGraph/blob/cbd3772e44cc42e2c68c45d683dec58f1ba8f115/AutoGraph/AutoGraph.swift#L100